# Embedded Pig program without property file

Tags: apache-pig

I have written a embedded Pig program which execute on my machine and perform query on the server(hadoop machine) and stores the results. But in this i am giving pig.property file to my class path.

Can we write Pig-Embedded program without giving Pig.property file??

Comment: the other way is to hard code the values , but I am not sure you want to do it that way

Comment: But how we can set pig properties values? Is there any class?

Comment: check this page : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/start.html#properties

Comment: That works by using commands.But I want it through java(by using classes or API).

Anyhow thanks for reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use org.apache.pig.PigServer to run pig scripts from Java programs.

```
PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE);
pigServer.registerScript("scripts/test.pig");
```

Requires 'pig.properties' on classpath.

fs.default.name=hdfs://:
mapred.job.tracker=:
Or pass an instance of java.util.Properties to PigServer constructor.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("fs.default.name", "hdfs://<namenode-hostname>:<port>");
props.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker", "<jobtracker-hostname>:<port>");
PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE, props);
```

also check [this](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/EmbeddedPig)

Comment: I know how to write queries. I want to know how to set properties without using property file............

I tried in this way but I was not able to find setProperty() method. //shall i need to import any package for this?

Comment: afaik you can do java.lang.System.setProperty()

Comment: hey @satya i think this "java.lang.System.setProperty()" belongs to that system not our pig .// i am not sure

Comment: Can you tell what are the necessary properties which we need to set?

Comment: registerJar / registerQuery/store

Comment: those things are require to execute a query in embedded programming.. I am asking about the properties which were in pig.property file.

Comment: fs.default.name / mapred.jobtracker, also, in case the answer helped , like it

Comment: Thanks @Satya. Thats what i wanted.